# Не видит функции из QT библиотек в XCode (MacOS)

Tags: c++, qt, xcode, qimage

Я создал проект в ***QT Creator*** и перекомпилировал с помощью командной строки проект так, чтобы появился **.xcodeproj** файл, и я мог продолжить кодинг уже в **XCode**.
Сам код: я подгружаю в программу картинку (через `argv[]`, один из которых - путь к файлу) и применяю к ней созданные мною фильтры, затем вывожу результат. 
Использую `QImage`, `setRgb`, `QColor`, `image.red/blue/green()`, `image.width/height()`, `setPixelColor`, `pixelColor`. Каждый фильтр - класс. Подключаю библиотеки к header-у (а сам header в main и .cpp) следующие:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include "qimage.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
```

Пример кода фильтра:

```
QImage Invert_Filter::CalculateNewImagePixMap(const QImage& photo, int radius) {
        QImage result_Image(photo);
        for (int x = 0; x< photo.width();x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < photo.width(); y++) {
                QColor photo_color = photo.pixelColor(x, y);
                photo_color.setRgb(
                    255 - photo_color.red(),
                    255 - photo_color.green(),
                    255 - photo_color.blue()
                                  );
                result_Image.setPixelColor(x, y, photo_color);

            }
        return result_Image;
    }
```

Но никак не могу справится с ошибкой после Build (компиляции):
[image]

Это все **при том**, что у меня есть файлы этой библиотеки (qimage), сама программа не показывает, что не нашла библиотеку, header файл и тому подобное. В общем, до компиляции проблем **не возникает**, все находит. А после выдает эти ошибки и не запускается. Пересобирать пробовал, очищать проект тоже и потом собирать снова. BitCode отключен.

Сразу скажу, этот же код работает без проблем на **Visual Studio 2019 под Windows 10**. Перешел на XCode, вылезло это.

Версия **QT 5.12.7**.
macOS **Catalina 15.10**.
XCode самый свежий из AppStore.

Comment: "Подключаю библиотеки к header-у" - нет. Вы не библиотеки подключаете, а включаете заголовочные файлы в свой заголовочный файл. Покажите pro файл, пожалуйста.

Comment: @vt-egorov, QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

Comment: Видимо,надо подключить библиотеку, содержащую класс QImage. qt += gui может быть вместо qt -= gui? В документации к QImage написано что-нибудь?

Comment: Да, там прям так и написано в шапке: `QT += gui` 

[QImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html)

Comment: @vt-egorov, да, из-за qt-=gui не работало) Удивительно, что там изначально минус стоял. И не додумался бы, благодарю.

Comment: @vt-egorov, слушай, все работает, но во время компиляции выводит следующее: 'QImage::setPixelColor: called on monochrome or indexed format'. На visual studio 2019 такой же код работает правильно и применяет фильтры к фото. Тут же никаких изменений, фильтры не работают, будто setPixelColor просто не меняет цвет пикселя. Не знаешь в чем проблема?

Comment: С одними фото работает, с другими нет. Хотя формат одинаковый, как и размер. Интереса ради спрашиваю

Comment: "Не работает" - очень плохое описание проблемы. Создайте ещё один тикет, подробно опишите шаги, которые нужно выполнить для получения "не работающего" результата. Подробно опишите что Вы имеете в виду под "работающим" результатом. Желательно - с примером входных и выходных данных. Ну и саму тестовую программку желательно, чтобы можно было скопировать, скомпилировать, запустить и посмотреть в отладчике/логи добавить. Ну в общем, сделать за Вас то что Вам нужно, но не тратя на это кучу своего времени.

Comment: А, ну да. Ещё макбук купить. Забыл.